# How to extract numbers with multiple decimal points from text in Google Sheets?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, decimal

I'm trying to extract a software version (pure numbers and decimals) from a text string in a cell, but because it has multiple decimals places I can't get the full result.

Examples (Input --> Output):

```
Plugin Version v4.5.2 Available --> 4.5.2
New Plugin v1.15.49 Available --> 1.15.49
```

So far I'm working with this formula, but it only gives me the first decimal result, it can't handle 2 decimals because these are software version numbers, not real numbers.

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"-*\d*\.?\d+")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1;"(-*\d*[\.?\d+]+)")
```

Explanation:
The original:

```
-*\d*\.?\d+
```

matches:

- `-*`: `0` to `n` `-` characters followed by:
- `\d*`: `0` to `n` decimal characters (`0-9`), followed by:
- `\.?`: `0` to `1` `.` character(s) (it has to be escaped, otherwise it means "any character"), followed by:
- `\d+`: `1` to `n` decimal characters.

We now:

- wrap `\.?\d+` into a "selection" (`[...]`)
- and match `1` to `n`(`+`) of its occurences: `[\.?\d+]+`
- additionally(not mandatory) enclose all in a "capturing group" (`(...)`) ...we could also: extract parts of it.

---

- [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tCiYLyzEurpBXnamnv83lJSzhE0tzr2AzooGvKOg9dA/edit?usp=sharing)
- https://www.google.com/search?q=regex+tutorial

Answer (score 3):

You can also try

```
=regexextract(A1; "[0-9.]+")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the number after `v`,

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"v([\d\.]+)")
```

- `\d` any digit
- `\.` literal `.`
- `[]+` match one or more of any of the characters inside []

Comment: All answers work. I appreciate the help!